# Group Datetime in panda into three hourly intervals

Tags: python, datetime, pandas

I want to modify this SO topic [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16266019/python-pandas-group-datetime-column-into-hour-and-minute-aggregations) to three hourly interval.
I have a database of events at minute resolution. I need to group them in three hourly, and extract the count of this grouping.

The output would ideally look something like a table like the following:

```
3hourly    count
0          10
3          3
6          5
9          2
...
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You haven't provided much detail, but you can use the 'TimeGrouper':

```
df.groupby(pd.TimeGrouper(key='your_time_column', freq='3H')).count()
```

The `key` parameter is optional if your time is the index.

Comment: I realize that yes i haven't given all details. 1) 3T is 3 minutes, so it should be 3h (i tried and 3h transforms the datetime column in 3hourly, 2) it sums the values of the first columns, so it doesn't properly count the values. if I use .count() works! if you correct 3T to 3h and sum to count i will mark it as correct

Comment: @claire thanks for the clarifications, I have edited my answer.