# using Python, How to group a column in Dataframe by the hour?

Tags: python, datetime, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I have a python dataframe (`df1`) which has a column time.  I converted the column into a datetime series using `pd.to_datetime(df1['time'])`.  Now I get a column like this:

```
2016-08-24 00:00:00  2016-08-13  00:00:00   
2016-08-24 00:00:00  2016-08-13  00:00:00     
2016-08-24 00:00:00  2016-08-13  00:00:00   
2016-08-24 00:00:00  2016-08-13  00:00:00  
2016-08-24 00:00:01  2016-08-13  00:00:01   
2016-08-24 00:00:01  2016-08-13  00:00:01   
2016-08-24 00:00:02  2016-08-13  00:00:02  
2016-08-24 00:00:02  2016-08-13  00:00:02     
2016-08-24 00:00:02  2016-08-13  00:00:02    
2016-08-24 00:00:02  2016-08-13  00:00:02     
2016-08-24 00:00:02  2016-08-13  00:00:02     
2016-08-24 00:00:02  2016-08-13  00:00:02     
2016-08-24 00:00:02  2016-08-13  00:00:02    
2016-08-24 00:00:02  2016-08-13  00:00:02    
2016-08-24 00:00:02  2016-08-13  00:00:02     
....

2016-08-24 23:59:59  2016-08-13  00:00:02
```

Essentially, I want the first column to be grouped by the hour, so that I can see how many entries are there in 1 hour.  Any help will be great.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using @jezrael setup.

```
df.resample(rule='H', how='count').rename(columns = {'time':'count'})

                      count
2016-08-24 00:00:00      1
2016-08-24 01:00:00      3
2016-08-24 02:00:00      1
```

Comment: Yes  This works if I use groupby for a single column.  Do you know what happens when we use Multi column grouping?

Answer (score 2):

Use [`resample`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html):

```
#pandas version 0.18.0 and higher
df = df.resample('H').size()

#pandas version below 0.18.0
#df = df.resample('H', 'size')

print (df)
2016-08-24 00:00:00    1
2016-08-24 01:00:00    3
2016-08-24 02:00:00    1
Freq: H, dtype: int64
```

If need output as `DataFrame`:

```
df = df.resample('H').size().rename('count').to_frame()
print (df)
                     count
2016-08-24 00:00:00      1
2016-08-24 01:00:00      3
2016-08-24 02:00:00      1
```

---

Or you can remove from `DatetimeIndex` `minutes` and `seconds` by converting to `<M8[h]` and then aggregating [`size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'time': {pd.Timestamp('2016-08-24 01:00:00'): pd.Timestamp('2016-08-13 00:00:00'), pd.Timestamp('2016-08-24 01:00:01'): pd.Timestamp('2016-08-13 00:00:01'), pd.Timestamp('2016-08-24 01:00:02'): pd.Timestamp('2016-08-13 00:00:02'), pd.Timestamp('2016-08-24 02:00:02'): pd.Timestamp('2016-08-13 00:00:02'), pd.Timestamp('2016-08-24 00:00:00'): pd.Timestamp('2016-08-13 00:00:00')}})
print (df)
                                   time
2016-08-24 00:00:00 2016-08-13 00:00:00
2016-08-24 01:00:00 2016-08-13 00:00:00
2016-08-24 01:00:01 2016-08-13 00:00:01
2016-08-24 01:00:02 2016-08-13 00:00:02
2016-08-24 02:00:02 2016-08-13 00:00:02

df= df.groupby([df.index.values.astype('<M8[h]')]).size()
print (df)
2016-08-24 00:00:00    1
2016-08-24 01:00:00    3
2016-08-24 02:00:00    1
dtype: int64
```

Comment: My problem is I have multiple columns that I am grouping by.  My code currently is

df2 = df1['count'].groupby([df1['sc-status],df1[cs-method],df1[time]).count()

Using the above code, and using my current data, I get time as it is in my input file (random requests through the hour).  I am struggling to go to the next step which is to group this grouped object (df2) every hour.  Hope this makes sense

Answer (score 1):

You can use `pandas.DatetimeIndex` as follows.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# An example of time period
drange = pd.date_range('2016-08-01 00:00:00', '2016-09-01 00:00:00',
                       freq='10min')

N = len(drange)

# The number of columns without 'time' is three.
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(N, 3))
df['time'] = drange

time_col = pd.DatetimeIndex(df['time'])

gb = df.groupby([time_col.year,
                 time_col.month,
                 time_col.day,
                 time_col.hour])

for col_name, gr in gb:
    print(gr)  # If you want to see only the length, use print(len(gr))
```

[References]
[Python Pandas: Group datetime column into hour and minute aggregations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16266019/python-pandas-group-datetime-column-into-hour-and-minute-aggregations)

Comment: Hi @Daewon lee....thank you for the answer.  When I use this code, it throws an error saying Series object has no value hour.  Any thoughts?

Comment: @Vijay Which version of Python do you use? The above code has been test in Anaconda Python 3.5 (64bit) at Windows 10 64bit. (And which version of Pandas do you use? Mine is 0.18.1)