# grouping all days python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, time-series

I have a Dataframe that changed it to time series. The date range is from 2013 till 2017. I would like to group all the data by hour on a day.
For example all the Mondays together and represented hourly, then all the Tuesdays. At the end I would have 168 (24*7) rows.
What is the best way to do so ?

I have this sample after the resampling:

```
2017-01-17 00:00:00    NaN
2017-01-17 01:00:00    NaN
2017-01-17 02:00:00    NaN
2017-01-17 03:00:00    NaN
2017-01-17 04:00:00    1.0
2017-01-17 05:00:00    NaN
2017-01-17 06:00:00    NaN
2017-01-17 07:00:00    NaN
2017-01-17 08:00:00    NaN
2017-01-17 09:00:00    1.0
2017-01-17 10:00:00    3.0
2017-01-17 11:00:00    3.0
2017-01-17 12:00:00    3.0
2017-01-17 13:00:00    5.0
2017-01-17 14:00:00    2.0
2017-01-17 15:00:00    1.0
2017-01-17 16:00:00    2.0
2017-01-17 17:00:00    1.0
2017-01-17 18:00:00    1.0
2017-01-17 19:00:00    1.0
2017-01-17 20:00:00    NaN
2017-01-17 21:00:00    NaN
2017-01-17 22:00:00    NaN
2017-01-17 23:00:00    NaN        
2017-01-24 10:00:00    14.0
2017-01-24 11:00:00    14.0
2017-01-24 12:00:00    5.0
2017-01-24 13:00:00    21.0
2017-01-24 14:00:00    14.0
2017-01-24 15:00:00    7.0
2017-01-24 16:00:00    9.0
2017-01-24 17:00:00    2.0
2017-01-24 18:00:00    1.0
2017-01-24 19:00:00    NaN
2017-01-24 20:00:00    NaN
2017-01-24 21:00:00    2.0
```

I would like to have something like:

```
                   (count sum)
Monday:    00:00     xx 
           01:00     xx
           ...
           23:00     xx
Tuesday:   00:00     xx
           01:00     xx
           ...
           23:00     xx
```

Comment: Your description is a bit too high level to really offer a concrete suggestion. Can you show any code?

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16266019/python-pandas-group-datetime-column-into-hour-and-minute-aggregations

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you can [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html)  by [`dayofweek`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DatetimeIndex.dayofweek.html) and [`hour`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DatetimeIndex.hour.html) with aggregating some function e.g. `sum`:

```
np.random.seed(100)
start = pd.to_datetime('2013-02-24 04:00:00')
rng = pd.date_range(start, periods=100, freq='3H')

#DataFrame has DatetimeIndex
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': np.random.randint(10, size=100)}, index=rng)  
print (df)
                     a
2013-02-24 04:00:00  8
2013-02-24 07:00:00  8
2013-02-24 10:00:00  3
2013-02-24 13:00:00  7
2013-02-24 16:00:00  7
2013-02-24 19:00:00  0
2013-02-24 22:00:00  4
2013-02-25 01:00:00  2
2013-02-25 04:00:00  5
...
...
```

```
print (df.index.weekday_name)
['Sunday' 'Sunday' 'Sunday' 'Sunday' 'Sunday' 'Sunday' 'Sunday' 'Monday'
 'Monday' 'Monday' 'Monday' 'Monday' 'Monday' 'Monday' 'Monday' 'Tuesday'
 'Tuesday' 'Tuesday' 'Tuesday' 'Tuesday' 'Tuesday' 'Tuesday' 'Tuesday'
 'Wednesday' 'Wednesday' 'Wednesday' 'Wednesday' 'Wednesday' 'Wednesday'
 'Wednesday' 'Wednesday' 'Thursday' 'Thursday' 'Thursday' 'Thursday'
 'Thursday' 'Thursday' 'Thursday' 'Thursday' 'Friday' 'Friday' 'Friday'
 'Friday' 'Friday' 'Friday' 'Friday' 'Friday' 'Saturday' 'Saturday'
 'Saturday' 'Saturday' 'Saturday' 'Saturday' 'Saturday' 'Saturday' 'Sunday'
 'Sunday' 'Sunday' 'Sunday' 'Sunday' 'Sunday' 'Sunday' 'Sunday' 'Monday'
 'Monday' 'Monday' 'Monday' 'Monday' 'Monday' 'Monday' 'Monday' 'Tuesday'
 'Tuesday' 'Tuesday' 'Tuesday' 'Tuesday' 'Tuesday' 'Tuesday' 'Tuesday'
 'Wednesday' 'Wednesday' 'Wednesday' 'Wednesday' 'Wednesday' 'Wednesday'
 'Wednesday' 'Wednesday' 'Thursday' 'Thursday' 'Thursday' 'Thursday'
 'Thursday' 'Thursday' 'Thursday' 'Thursday' 'Friday' 'Friday' 'Friday'
 'Friday' 'Friday']

print (df.index.hour)
[ 4  7 10 13 16 19 22  1  4  7 10 13 16 19 22  1  4  7 10 13 16 19 22  1  4
  7 10 13 16 19 22  1  4  7 10 13 16 19 22  1  4  7 10 13 16 19 22  1  4  7
 10 13 16 19 22  1  4  7 10 13 16 19 22  1  4  7 10 13 16 19 22  1  4  7 10
 13 16 19 22  1  4  7 10 13 16 19 22  1  4  7 10 13 16 19 22  1  4  7 10 13]
```

```
print (df.groupby([df.index.weekday_name, df.index.hour])['a'].sum())
Friday     1     13
           4     10
           7      6
           10    13
           13    11
           16     2
           19     0
           22     8
Monday     1      6
           4     12
           7      8
           10     5
           13    11
...
...
```

If `DataFrame` has `date` column:

```
np.random.seed(100)
start = pd.to_datetime('2013-02-24 04:00:00')
rng = pd.date_range(start, periods=100, freq='3H')

df = pd.DataFrame({'date': rng, 'a': np.random.randint(10, size=100)})  
print (df)
    a                date
0   8 2013-02-24 04:00:00
1   8 2013-02-24 07:00:00
2   3 2013-02-24 10:00:00
3   7 2013-02-24 13:00:00
4   7 2013-02-24 16:00:00
5   0 2013-02-24 19:00:00
6   4 2013-02-24 22:00:00
7   2 2013-02-25 01:00:00
8   5 2013-02-25 04:00:00

print (df.groupby([df.date.dt.weekday_name, df.date.dt.hour])['a'].sum())
date       date
Friday     1       13
           4       10
           7        6
           10      13
           13      11
           16       2
           19       0
           22       8
Monday     1        6
           4       12
           7        8
           10       5
           13      11
```

If `Series` with `DatetimeIndex`:

```
s = pd.Series(np.random.randint(10, size=100), index=rng)  
print (s)
2013-02-24 04:00:00    8
2013-02-24 07:00:00    8
2013-02-24 10:00:00    3
2013-02-24 13:00:00    7
2013-02-24 16:00:00    7
2013-02-24 19:00:00    0
2013-02-24 22:00:00    4
2013-02-25 01:00:00    2
2013-02-25 04:00:00    5
2013-02-25 07:00:00    2
2013-02-25 10:00:00    2
2013-02-25 13:00:00    2

print (s.groupby([s.index.weekday_name, s.index.hour]).sum())
Friday     1     13
           4     10
           7      6
           10    13
           13    11
           16     2
           19     0
           22     8
Monday     1      6
           4     12
           7      8
           10     5
           13    11
```

Last for `DataFrame` add `reset_index()`:

```
df = s.groupby([s.index.weekday_name, s.index.hour]).sum().reset_index()
df.columns = ['days','hours','val']
print (df)
         days  hours  val
0      Friday      1   13
1      Friday      4   10
2      Friday      7    6
3      Friday     10   13
4      Friday     13   11
5      Friday     16    2
6      Friday     19    0
7      Friday     22    8
8      Monday      1    6
9      Monday      4   12
10     Monday      7    8
11     Monday     10    5
12     Monday     13   11
```

EDIT by comment:

```
print (s)
2017-01-24 10:00:00    14.0
2017-01-24 11:00:00    14.0
2017-01-24 12:00:00     5.0
2017-01-24 13:00:00    21.0
2017-01-24 14:00:00    14.0
2017-01-24 15:00:00     7.0
2017-01-24 16:00:00     9.0
2017-01-24 17:00:00     2.0
2017-01-24 18:00:00     1.0
2017-01-24 19:00:00     NaN
2017-01-24 20:00:00     NaN
2017-01-24 21:00:00     2.0
Name: a, dtype: float64

df = s.groupby([s.index.weekday_name, s.index.hour]).sum().reset_index()
df.columns = ['days','hours','val']
print (df)
       days  hours   val
0   Tuesday     10  14.0
1   Tuesday     11  14.0
2   Tuesday     12   5.0
3   Tuesday     13  21.0
4   Tuesday     14  14.0
5   Tuesday     15   7.0
6   Tuesday     16   9.0
7   Tuesday     17   2.0
8   Tuesday     18   1.0
9   Tuesday     19   NaN
10  Tuesday     20   NaN
11  Tuesday     21   2.0
```

Comment: You solution is very close, how can I add the hours that have nans ?

Comment: Can you change your sample data with these NaN ?

Comment: @datascana - I test it and it works, see edit od my answer. Or do you need something else?