# Issues with grouping pandas dataframe by hour

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

First off, my data set is shown below

[image: here]

What I'd like to do is group my columns by `pickup_datetime` hour. I've found related questions on [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16266019/python-pandas-group-datetime-column-into-hour-and-minute-aggregations) but for some reason the solution doesn't seem to work. I've included my attemps below.

I first started off with this:

```
df["dropoff_datetime"] = pd.to_datetime(df["dropoff_datetime"])
df["pickup_datetime"] = pd.to_datetime(df["pickup_datetime"])

test = df.groupby(df.hour).sum()
```

And I got the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'hour'
```

Then I tried this:

```
test = df.groupby(df.dropoff_datetime.hour).sum()
```

And I got the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'hour'
```

I'm a bit confused because it seems like my situation is the same as the question linked above. I'm not sure why I am getting errors though. Any help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 6, accepted):

we can use [Series.dt.hour](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.hour.html) accessor:

```
test = df.groupby(df['pickup_datetime'].dt.hour).sum()
```

Here is an example describing the difference:

```
In [136]: times = pd.to_datetime(['2017-08-01 13:13:13', '2017-08-01 20:20:20'])

In [137]: times
Out[137]: DatetimeIndex(['2017-08-01 13:13:13', '2017-08-01 20:20:20'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None)

In [138]: type(times)
Out[138]: pandas.core.indexes.datetimes.DatetimeIndex

In [139]: times.hour
Out[139]: Int64Index([13, 20], dtype='int64')
```

as shown above `DatetimeIndex` has "direct" `.hour` accessor, but `Series` of `datetime` dtype has `.dt.hour` accessor:

```
In [140]: df = pd.DataFrame({'Date': times})

In [141]: df
Out[141]:
                 Date
0 2017-08-01 13:13:13
1 2017-08-01 20:20:20

In [142]: type(df.Date)
Out[142]: pandas.core.series.Series

In [143]: df['Date'].dt.hour
Out[143]:
0    13
1    20
Name: Date, dtype: int64
```

If we set `Date` column as an index:

```
In [146]: df.index = df['Date']

In [147]: df
Out[147]:
                                   Date
Date
2017-08-01 13:13:13 2017-08-01 13:13:13
2017-08-01 20:20:20 2017-08-01 20:20:20
```

it becomes:

```
In [149]: type(df.index)
Out[149]: pandas.core.indexes.datetimes.DatetimeIndex
```

so we can access it directly (without `.dt` accessor) again:

```
In [148]: df.index.hour
Out[148]: Int64Index([13, 20], dtype='int64', name='Date')
```

Answer (score 1):

Need `.dt` because working with `Series` - [`Series.dt.hour`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.hour.html):

```
test = df.groupby(df.dropoff_datetime.dt.hour).sum()
```

---

But if `DatetimeIndex`, omit it - [`DatetimeIndex.hour`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DatetimeIndex.hour.html):

```
test = df.groupby(df.index.hour).sum()
```