# Pandas: group dataframe by time of a day and make a plot on one figure

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, time-series, pandas-groupby

I've seen dozens of similar questions but I couldn't make a final effect like I want.

Data frame structure is filled with measurements taken nearly every minute (25k+ rows):

```
                                     some_val
...
2020-02-22 00:00:00                  1.1
2020-02-22 00:01:01                  1.4
2020-02-22 00:02:01                  1.5
...
2020-02-23 00:00:05                  1.7
2020-02-23 00:01:05                  1.6
2020-02-23 00:02:06                  1.6
...
2020-02-24 00:00:02                  1.4
2020-02-24 00:01:03                  1.8
2020-02-24 00:02:03                  1.3
```

I want to group that data frame by each minute of a day - so first group (time of a day 00:00) should consist of [1.1, 1.7, 1.4] and so on.

Then I want to see some trends by plotting it on 1 figure where:

- X axis is time with step of 1 minute (00:00, 00:01, ..., 23:59)
- Y axis are `some_val` - as many measurements per each X time as they are in each group

For now I don't want to `count()` or `mean()` anything. Just simple grouping, plotting everything on 1 figure and saving it to file.

As I read I should be able to use pandas `groupby` or `resample` along with `matplotlib.pyplot` but somehow I couldn't manage to do it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: maybe duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16266019/python-pandas-group-datetime-column-into-hour-and-minute-aggregations

Comment: As it suggests some solutions for grouping (that I tried before), it doesn't solve my problem with plotting all the data on 1 figure.

Answer (score 1):

**Solution Code**

```
import pandas as pd

data={'Date':['2020-02-22T00:00:00.000000000', '2020-02-22T00:01:00.000000000',
           '2020-02-22T00:02:00.000000000'],'some_val':[1.1, 1.4, 1.5]}
    df=pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)
```

**Plotting**

```
import matplotlib .pyplot as plt
df['Date']=pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])#Converting Date to datetime 
df.set_index(df['Date'], inplace=True)#Setting Date as index
df['x']= df.index.minute #Extracting minutes
df.plot(x='x', y='some_val')
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but your solution plots all the data sorted by each minute in 1 hour period. My question was to plot all the data by each minute in 1 day period.

Answer (score 0):

If you need each minute in a day please try;

```
data={'Date':['2020-02-22T00:00:00.000000000', '2020-02-22T00:01:00.000000000',
       '2020-02-22T00:02:00.000000000','2020-02-23T00:00:00.000000000', '2020-02-23T00:01:00.000000000',
       '2020-02-23T00:02:00.000000000'],'some_val':[1.1, 1.4, 1.5,2.1, 2.4, 2.5]}
    df=pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)
    df['Date']=pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
   df.set_index(df['Date'], inplace=True)
   df['x']= df.index.minute
   for x, df2 in df.groupby(df.index.date):
    df2.plot(x='x', y='some_val')
    plt.title(x)
```