# Grouby with datetime in two dimensions

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I am checking this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16266019/python-pandas-group-datetime-column-into-hour-and-minute-aggregations) already, but somehow it is not working.

I currently have a dataframe with two columns:

[image]

When I check the column types I get:

```
Datum        datetime64[ns]
MIPS                float64
```

So now I want to groupby the day and the hour:

```
df.groupby([df['Datum'].dt.day, df['Datum'].dt.hour])['MIPS'].sum().reset_index()
```

But I get the following error:

> ValueError: cannot insert Datum, already exists

Is it because he cannot create a grouped dataframe with two times the same name? How can I avoid that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can rename both `Series` for avoid `MultiIndex` with same names:

```
df.groupby([df['Datum'].dt.day.rename('Day'), 
            df['Datum'].dt.hour.rename('Hour')])['MIPS'].sum().reset_index()
```