# I am trying to convert 31*24 (744) data points into 31 by calculating average value for each hour in a month using .loc function

Tags: python, pandas

I want to calculate the average value for each hour in a month, based on values for each hour for all days in the month. For example, based on demand for Hour 1 in each day for January (i.e., from Day 1, H1, Day 2, H1, Day 3, H1..... to Avg H1).

I am using a lengthy process here by manually averaging over the row numbers corresponding to hour 1 for January:

```
jh1 = df1.loc[[0,24,48,72,96,120,144,168,192,216,240,264,288,312,336,360,384,408,432,456,480,504,528,552,576,600,624,648,672,696,720]].mean()
print(jh1)
```

I want to do this average hourly data for each month. Any help on the right approach with appropriate commands will be very helpful.

Comment: Please do not post images of code or images of data. Post the actual code and actual data as text. If you put it between ``` ``` it will render as code. Please edit and update your post.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! 
Higher chances of getting answers come after reading [ask]. In particular, code and data are required to be posted as [text, not images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors/285557#285557)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python Pandas: Group datetime column into hour and minute aggregations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16266019/python-pandas-group-datetime-column-into-hour-and-minute-aggregations)

Comment: Please provide a proper MRE (see [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20109391/14311263)). Helping is almost impossible without proper knowledge about how your data look like.

Comment: One simple approach you could try is `df.groupby(df.index % 24).mean()` (`df` your dataframe).